# Trouble installing a kernel driver for Yiynova tablet on Linux Mint 18.2

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-mint

I got a Yiynova (MVP10U) tablet and haven't had the best luck getting it to work well on my Windows 10 laptop, so I thought I'd see how Linux would do.
I'm following this older tutorial: [How To install a non-Wacom (Yiynova) tablet into Linux](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=185433) and am stuck on step two... For some reason cd isn't finding my kernel in the directory.

```
 ~ $ cd /home/crysenley/Documents/MintModifications/Drivers/digimend-kernel-drivers-5
bash: cd: /home/crysenley/Documents/MintModifications/Drivers/digimend-kernel-drivers-5: No such file or directory

 ~ $ cd /home/crysenley/Documents/MintModifications/Drivers/digimend-kernel-drivers-5.tar.gz
bash: cd: /home/crysenley/Documents/MintModifications/Drivers/digimend-kernel-drivers-5.tar.gz: Not a directory
```

When I don't include the file name it seems to work just fine until I try to point it to the file again:

```
  ~ $ cd /home/crysenley/Documents/MintModifications/Drivers/
  ~/Documents/MintModifications/Drivers $ digimend-kernel-drivers-5
 WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

 digimend-kernel-drivers-5: command not found
 ~/Documents/MintModifications/Drivers $ digimend-kernel-drivers-5.tar.gz
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

digimend-kernel-drivers-5.tar.gz: command not found
```

I'm sure the solution is a simple one, I'm just not that familiar with Linux, still. I tried searching up answers, but the ones I found didn't seem to relate to my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out I just needed to extract the tar.gz file before using it... Didn't realize tar files are to be extracted without other programs. ^^;